# How do I make a ray effect in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, stroke, anchor-point

What I've been doing is copied each stroke, selecting the end anchor point and moving it using the arrow keys:

[image]

Is there an easier way to do the following "semi-circle ray effect" in Illustrator?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick and easy way... use a Transform effect (*Effect → Distort & Transform → Transform...*) on a single line, setting an appropriate number of copies and rotation angle<sup>*</sup>. Set the transform origin to the edge which you want to be the center of the "ray"...

[image]

<sup>*</sup>Quick tip: you can do basic math in the angle input; so if you want 10 rays over 180 degrees, you input `180/10`, and it will set the correct angle for you.

If you want varying line lengths you can create a single line for each different length with a Transform effect on each, adjusting the rotation angle and number of copies as needed...

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Just a few simple rotate and duplicate steps. Working from the center point and rotating around it, starting with a line segment on either the left or right.

1. **The longest line** would be drawn as a horizontal then rotated and duplicated at 45° four times. For precision, make the two dots on the first line, then delete the extra for the two diagonals.
   [image]  [image]
2. **The medium length line** would be drawn horizontally then rotated 22.5° to get it in the first position. Then rotate and dupe 45° three more times for the remainders.
   [image]  [image]
3. **The shortest line** would again be drawn horizontally, then rotated 11.25° to it's first position. Rotate and dupe at 22.5° seven more times for the rest.
   [image]  [image]

Done.